# Is it possible to password protect an individual database in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, password-protection

I am using MySQL workbench 6.2.3. I want limit user access to an individual database.When one trying to open a database after getting in a connection, he/she should enter user name and password. Is there any provision to grant access to a database after entering valid username and password?

Comment: You can grant a user to have access to a single database. What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to grant access rights to individual user. It worked but didn't solve my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to require an additional password for a user once he logged in. Control access via the normal MySQL login. The user name used for that can be configured to have only access to the objects you want. The used user name decides what is allowed and what is not.

For commercial MySQL editions you can also use the new [MySQL Firewall](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/firewall.html), which allows only a set of previously learned queries to be run by a given user. It's not a second login, but you can fine tune access levels for a given user.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you are trying to achieve but you can do the following to grant a user the access to a single database and all its tables.

You login as root with "`mysql -u root`"

Then execute : `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SpecificUserDB.* To 'TheUser'@'yourserver' IDENTIFIED BY 'secretpwd';`

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer will grant access rights to the user. But, I want a user to enter username and password if he wants to access database from MySQL workbench like MS Access's way of accessing database.

Comment: Yes, so in MySQL Workbench once you create a new connection to the server, the user can enter the username & password you defined. This user will only be able to access that table.

Comment: I understood your stand completely. If you have used MS Access, there it has provision of allowing a user to enter username and password if he wants to access any particular database after logging in. I am interested to know whether a similar kind of feature exist in MySQL workbench also.